# Deny User Access to All sys and INFORMATION_SCHEMA views and sys stored procedures in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-permissions, user-roles, access-rights

I hope you can help me with this.

We have an application that we need to restrict access to. The application will be using login TestApp.

I've been testing this using SQL Server Management Studio v 17.9.1 and we are using SQL Server 2016.

This Login will have access to all tables, stored procedures, views, functions and triggers within its own schema Test in the tatabase: `Testing`, and only to certain tables from `dbo` schema that we specify in the permissions of the `TestAPP` user.

I've used the following script to achieve that.

The problem we are having is that the Login can access all system views and stored procedures and we don't want this level of access (attached pictures [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iC74.jpg))  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5tn0.jpg)
This login shouldn't be able to do those under schema TEST.

1. Create, drop, alter tables from `Test` schema
2. Create, alter, drop views from `Test` schema
3. Create, alter, drop stored procedures from `Test` schema

We are trying to use Roles so that we don't have to specify each and every sys object that we want to deny access to.

I've created the Role [db_TestExecutor] and attached the role to the user. and then gave specific permissions for the dbo tables but still they can see all sys objects.

Used SQL code below:

```
USE [Testing]
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Test] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]

GO

CREATE ROLE [db_TestExecutor]
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::Test TO [db_TestExecutor]
GO

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::Test TO [db_TestExecutor]


USE [mASTER]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [name] = 'TestApp')

                    BEGIN
                        CREATE LOGIN TestApp WITH PASSWORD=N'Password123', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[tempdb], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
                    END

USE [Testing]
GO
CREATE USER [TestApp] FOR LOGIN [TestApp] 
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_TestExecutor] ADD MEMBER  [TestApp]
GO
GRANT INSERT ON [dbo].[tblOrders] TO [TestApp]
GO              
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[tblOrders] TO [TestApp]
GO              
GRANT UPDATE ON [dbo].[tblOrders] TO [TestApp]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[test] TO [TestApp]
```

I expect the TestApp login to be able to see only objects from Test schema and only certain dbo tables.

Please see below the desired result:

[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please specify which DBMS you are using since each has different mechanisms to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly using DENY on the role?

DENY EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::sys TO [db_TestExecutor]
GO

DENY SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::sys TO [db_TestExecutor]
GO

Comment: @ChrisHackett Dear Chris, I've tried that it doesn't work. I get the following error : The Select Permission was denied on the object 'extended_properties', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. I've also tried each one of those and they can still see them and open views and store procs. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @FDavidov I've been testing this under Sql Server Management Studio v 17.9.1 and we are using SQL Server 2016. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Karolina, unfortunately, I have no deep knowledge on SQL Server ADMIN, but I'm sure that what you want is achievable. Good luck!!!!